# Proof by contradiction of a variant of PHP

Tags: solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

Let $a_1, a_2,\ldots , a_n$ be positive integers.

> Prove that if $(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)-n+1$ pigeons are to be put in $n$ pigeonholes, then for some $i$, the statement "The $i^{th}$ pigeonhole must contain at least $a_i$ pigeons" must be true.

***My approach:***

Let us assume that this hypothesis is incorrect.

Let $p(i)$ denote the number of pigeons in $i^{th}$ pigeonhole.

Thus no $i\in \mathbb N$ exists such that $i^{th}$ pigeonhole contains at least $a_i$ pigeons.

$$\therefore p(i)<a_i\space \forall\ i\in \mathbb N$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} p(i)<\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$$
$$(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)-n+1<(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)$$
This gives us $1<n$ which certainly is true.

Where did I go wrong in my proof? Please help.

***THANKS***

Note: This is question number $3.3.12$ from the book 'The Art and Craft of Problem Solving' by Paul Zeitz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p(i)$ is an integer, $p(i)<a_i$ is equivalent to $p(i)\leq a_i-1$. Then we have the following,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}p(i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i-1)\\\implies(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)-n+1\leq(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)-n$$ which is a contradiction!

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thanks for this solution but I have a question. Why didn't it work when $p(i)<a_i$ was taken as argument?

Comment: That's the flaw of estimating an integer with strict inequality which creates problem in many other proofs. You will certainly encounter such more.

Comment: So whenever I encounter a strict inequality, should I try to change it so that it doesn't remian strict?

Comment: Yes. It will be best in case of variables which takes integer values

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Strict inequality does not say you the correct bound. In some cases that can be very weak bound. So transformation of a strict inequality to a $\leq$ or $\geq$ form is always better and stronger.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the statement 'at least'.  To ensure that no bin $i$ contains at least $a_i$ pigeons, you need to ensure that each bin $i$ contains at most $a_i-1$ of them. Therefore the total number of pigeons is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}p(i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_i-1)=(a_1+\cdots+a_n)-n<(a_1+\cdots+a_n)-n+1.
$$

Comment: Here you have said $
\sum_{i=1}^{n}p(i)<(a_1+\ldots+a_n)-n+1
$ but $(a_1+\ldots+a_n)-n+1$ IS the total number of pigeons.

Comment: Sorry, I see that this is the contradiction here.